# Vue.js event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus

I'm working on a vue single page project,and I use an empty Vue instance as a central event bus.But there is some problem when firing a event.

eventbus.js

```
import vue from 'Vue'
export default new vue({})
```

a.vue

```
import bus from '~js/eventBus'
methods: {
    go(name) {
        bus.$emit('setPartner', name);
            this.$router.go(-1);
    }
}
```

b.vue

```
import bus from '~js/eventBus'
data() {
         return {
           contract: {
               contractSubject: ''
           }
         }
     },
mounted(){

     bus.$once('setPartner', data => {
          this.contract.contractSubject = data;
     });
}
```

in b.vue file,I can recieve data,but I can't assign the value of data to 'this.contract.contractSubject'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment, but point restrictions.  It seems like you're only posting snippets of the code, so it's hard to get a full picture.  I assume that you've already set this.contract to be an Object?  I don't know what your data function looks like, and an error message would be helpful, but it sounds like you're trying to assign a field on an object that doesn't exist yet.

Edit

Thanks for the information.  I'm not sure if your edit to b.vue was a mistake when you copied things over to stackoverflow, but based on the code you've provided, my guess is that you wrote `data()` in the wrong place.  You have it inside `mounted()`, not as a key value of the component object, and thus `this.contract` won't access it.

I managed to get it working under the setup below

**a.vue**

```
import bus from './bus.js';

export default {
  name: 'sitea',
  methods: {
    go(name) {
      bus.$emit('setPartner', name);
    }
  }
}
```

**b.vue**

```
import bus from './bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'siteb',
  data() {
    return {
      contract: {
        contractSubject: ''
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    bus.$once('setPartner', data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.contract.contractSubject = data;
    });
  }
}
```

[More information](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

Comment: sorry for not giving you more specific information.But yes,this.contract is in data function.

Comment: That's alright, thanks for the additional info.  I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it was my carelessness.I'll try what you give me.Thanks again!